# Number format not working properly in xlsxwriter

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to set number format without decimal places for 2 created xlsxwriter formats:

```
text_wrap = wb.add_format()
text_wrap.set_text_wrap()
text_wrap.set_align('vcenter')
text_wrap.set_font_name('Arial')
text_wrap.set_font_size(10)

num_format = copy_format(wb, text_wrap)
num_format.set_num_format('0')

total_num_format = copy_format(wb, text_wrap)
total_num_format.set_bg_color(bg_color)
total_num_format.set_num_format('0')
```

where "wb" is instance of WorkBook class, `copy_format` is a custom function:

```
def copy_format(workbook, existing_format):
    """
    This function should be deleted when all reports with xlsxwriter
    will be rewritten to classes

    Give a format you want to extend and a dict of the properties you 
    want to extend it with, and you get them returned in a single format

    :rtype : xlsxwriter.format.Format
    """
    new_dict = {}
    for key, value in existing_format.__dict__.iteritems():
        if value:
            new_dict[key] = value
    del new_dict['escapes']

    return workbook.add_format(new_dict)
```

So, I'm applying num_format for one column which has formulas in its cells and total_num_format for cell with SUM of this column:

```
ws.write(0, 2, '=B1-A1', num_format)
ws.write(1, 2, '=B2-A2', num_format)
ws.write(2, 2, '=B3-A3', num_format)
ws.write(3, 2, '=B4-A4', num_format)

ws.write(4, 2, '=SUM(C1:C4)', total_num_format)
```

where "ws" is instance of WorkSheet class.

And I'm getting rounded results in first 4 cells as expected, but not rounded in last cell (total).

Is it xlsxwriter's bug, or am I doing something wrong?
What should I do to make my total cell rounded as well?

I'm sorry for my bad English and thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the difference between `nom_format` and `total_num_format`?

Comment: @michael, I'm setting bg color for second one in my code, I forgot to mention it, sorry, but it's the only difference

Comment: @michael I have assumption, that this is connected with sum of other formulas somehow

Comment: did you try to use `ws.write_formula(4, 2, '=SUM(C1:C4)', total_num_format)`?

Comment: @MrFuppes, yep, didn't work

Comment: was `bg_color` working in your cell ?

Comment: @Arihant, yep, color applied to cell as expected, only '0' didn't work

Comment: also, what does `copy_format` do, where do you get that function from? I tried to reproduce your problem without this function (just setting `text_wrap.set_num_format('0')` and using `text_wrap` as format) - cannot reproduce the problem. Cell is formatted correctly with `ws.write(4, 2, '=SUM(C1:C4)', text_wrap)`.

Comment: can you try `total_num_format = copy_format(wb, num_format)` and 
`total_num_format.set_bg_color(bg_color)` ?

Comment: @Arihant, already tried, didn't work

Comment: @MrFuppes this is custom function, using `.add_format` method, I'll add it to the question

Comment: And also there are more settings in every format, but they are similar, so I didn't mentioned it to make question shorter

Comment: can you try this `total_num_format.set_num_format(1)` ?
else try reordering the `set_num_format` and `set_bg_color` functions ?

Comment: @Arihant, thanks a lot for help! I found the same solution in issue posted in answer bellow, 1 instead '0' worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [issue](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/103), if briefly, it's a xlsxwriter bug, workaround is to use 1 (as number) instead of '0':

```
total_num_format.set_num_format(1)
```

Hope, this will save someone's time

Comment: That bug is closed so it shouldn’t be an issue anymore. What version of XlsxWriter are you using?

Comment: Ok, thanks! I will update it later and check how it works

Comment: @jmcnamara Is it possible to set a number format such that it just shows the formatted version on appearance and not in the formula? I used "0.00%" to show decimals as numbers and it shows in percent form in both the view and the underlying data.